# How to solve Leaks?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

So I have memory leaks in my game. I think its coming from Admob and game center integration. Any suggestion for tackling this problem? I tried locating the problem using leak instrument but I have no idea how to do that. Also is it worth solving the leaks? I have about 7 leaks every while.

```
//Ad banner

        self.banner = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
        self.banner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        self.banner.rootViewController = self
        let request: GADRequest = GADRequest()
        self.banner.load(request)
        self.banner.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: view.bounds.height - self.banner.frame.size.height, width: self.banner.frame.size.width, height: self.banner.frame.size.height)

        self.view.addSubview(self.banner!)


//gamecenter authentication 


    func authPlayer () {
            let player = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
            player.authenticateHandler = {
                (view, error) in
                if view != nil {
                    self.present(view!, animated: true,completion: nil)

                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: What is your log messages?

Comment: I guess it is something else... Oh wait... I could just guess :) You should post images from instruments and a code that you think it is relevant.

Comment: Start with deinits as Fluidity said... Also an easy way to see if Admob is your offender, is to remove all related Admob code and see if leaks happen.

Comment: Or see how to use Instruments to find leaks : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/FindingLeakedMemory.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `deinit` to your classes with a print message to determine which classes are not dying when they should. Then, you go to the places that these classes are instantiated and make them `weak` or `unowned` variables with an optional type.

If that doesn't fix it, then you may have issues with closures going on, but I would worry about learning closure capture leaks only AFTER you understand the basics of ARC.

Here is a great tutorial that shows how ARC works and how to track down leaks in more detail:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/134411/arc-memory-management-swift

To your second question, no, memory leaks may not be a huge concern for you. However, they may also be a huge concern. The way to find out is to leave your app on for the whole day, or spend half an hour going through the different levels and seeing if your memory usage keeps going up.

If your memory use keeps going up, then you have a problem that definitely needs fixing. Otherwise, your app is just using more resources than is needed, which isn't ideal, but not necessarily critical to fix either.